# Purpose of Android Account Manager?

Tags: android, passwords, account

What is the purpose of the `android.accounts.AccountManager` class?

The class docs say it

> provides access to a centralized registry of the user's online accounts.

And why is that useful?  The docs again say

> The user enters credentials (username and password) once per account, granting applications access to online resources with "one-click" approval.

1. So it's only about user convenience?  It saves you from always having to type in an id & password.
2. But the cost is that the ids and passwds for all your accounts are stored on the device, and thus vulnerable to being stolen.
3. And each server for which you have an id/passwd, has to participate too, correct?  So this is not used like the "field completion" of a browser form.  This requires the server,  on successful login, to give you a token which can be used (for a limited period) to reconnect to the server.

Could anyone comment on points 1, 2, and 3, and tell me if I am missing anything of significance?

Answer (score 2):

1) So it's only about user convenience? It saves you from always having to type in an id &       password.

answer- ya as far as i m concerned about the account manager , o would say yes it is only for 
user convenience.

2)But the cost is that the ids and passwds for all your accounts are stored on the device, and thus vulnerable to being stolen.

answer- ya u r right thts why we should avoid using account manager as possible.see this link below
http://security-n-tech.blogspot.com/2011/01/security-issue-exposed-by-android.html

question number 3) i have not much ideal about that